# Bound of word width in compact $p$-adic analytic group

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, profinite-groups, p-adic-groups

A theorem proved by A. Jaikin-Zapirain in [On the verbal width of finitely generated pro-$p$ groups](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.rmi/1218475356) says that:

> *If $G$ is a compact $p$-adic analytic group, then every word $w$ of a free group $F$ has finite width in $G$.*

Now, chosen some compact $p$-adic analytic group $G$, denote by $|w|_G$ the width of any word $w$ in $G$. Consider
$$S_G = \sup_w|w|_G$$
the supremum of all width words $w$ of a free group $F$ in $G$ (here is considered $G$ a group that is fixed). Jaikin-Zapirain's theorem do not give us information about $S_G$. Are any results known about $S_G$?

Comment: Could you provide a specific reference for the result you mention?

Comment: It's a question about $\sup_G\sup_w$, right? You seem to index on $G$ and $w$ with distinct notation so I'm not sure.

Comment: Anyway the sup over $G$ of the width in $G$ of the commutator word $xyx^{-1}y^{-1}$ is infinite, since it's already finite on finite groups, and even on finite $p$-groups.

Comment: @YCor, I make a bad notation, my ideia is that $G$ be a fixed group and the $\sup$ varying over $w$.

Comment: @AndreiSmolensky, the reference can be the paper "On the verbal width of finitely generated pro-$p$ groups".

Comment: The first natural question is maybe whether $S_G<\infty$ for every $G$ (unless you know this to hold?). What I readily see is that $S_G=1$ for $G\neq 1$ abelian.